# Virtual method crash with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, crash

I think I found a bug in MSVC's compiler (MSVC Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4).

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        printf("Base::print()\n");
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base()
    {
    }

    virtual void print()
    {
        printf("Derived::print()\n");
    }
};

class DerivedSquared : public Derived
{
public:
    DerivedSquared() : Derived()
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        printf("DerivedSquared::print()\n");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Base *obj1 = new Base();
    Base *obj2 = new Derived();
    Base *obj3 = new DerivedSquared();

    obj1->print();
    obj2->print();
    obj3->print();

    // Memory leaks are ALWAYS nasty :P
    delete obj1;

    // CRASH!!!
    // File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
    //  _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
    delete obj2;
    delete obj3;

    return 0;
}
```

The particularity in that code is that Base's printf() method is not virtual, while Derived's one is.
This doesn't happen with GCC (I've tested that with [codepad](http://codepad.org/)).
I wonder if this is an actual compiler bug or I'm missing something obvious.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can only delete a derived object safely through a base pointer if it has a virtual destructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **5.3.5/3** In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the
>   static type **shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined**.

Emphasis mine. Crashing is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. "Nothing bad appears to happen" is another.

Comment: Yeah, adding a virtual destructor to Base fixes the problem. I didn't know this requirement, it's amazing how one can still discover new things even after years of practice. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs without calling the 'print' functions, and can be resolved by adding a virtual destructor to each class.

Answer (score 0):

As for me then it looks like a bug. I mean calling the print function that ends with crash if you are speaking about this.

Comment: It's not the print() function which crashes, it's the delete.
However, this is not a bug, but rather an "undefined behavior", as pointed out by other users. :)

Comment: @ XDnl I have understood such a way that it is the print function that is the reason of the crash. I have no the realese of this compiler so I can not check.